# Does JGroup ReplicatedHashMap automatically obtain its initial state

Tags: jgroups

I am seeing this behavior in JGroup's ReplciatedHashMap which I don't think is correct. I have   two members A and B in a cluster. A puts some items in the replicated hash map and B sees the same items in its copy. Now A closes its channel and reopens it and creates the hash map. At this point, I expect A's hash map to contain the same contents as in B but A's hash map remain empty. My expectation was that the contents of hash map would be consistent through the cluster.

So, what am I doing wrong? Should I set the initial state upon view change? I am using "udp.xml" for the protocol specification and doing something very basic. Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: It appears that I need to call `state(timeout)` method. I am still wondering when it would make sense to created replcated hashmap and not initialize the state automatically. Can somebody explain this design choice?

Answer (score 0):

ReplicatedHashMap is an example, not a production-ready class.